# Filtering by custom dimension

Tags: universal-analytics

I created a hit scoped custom dimension called "type". Also I created a view with include filter "type" = "Books". However in reports I see click hits with other dimension values (e.g., Books Sci-Fi). Do I have to add also exclude filter for view?

Comment: I guess that my filter is wrong because target value in filter is treated as a reg. exp. Thus reg. exp. "Books" matches also "Books Sci-Fi". Updated filter to use "^Books$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially problem was that filter value have to be reg. exp. I changed it to ^Books$ and now hits with custom dimension "Books Sci-Fi" are excluded.